# Could not find gem 'pg x64-mingw32' in locally installed gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

Please help me get rid of this error

I am running Ruby on Rails on Windows 10

Could not find gem 'pg x64-mingw32' in locally installed gems.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWBlI.png)

Comment: I tried running : gem install 'pg' --platform=mingw --platform=mswin --platform=x64_mingw32
 but that didnt't fix it

Comment: I think, you should switch Ubuntu.

Comment: Could you clarify if you are running inside of bundler and a bit about how your environment is set up? It's a bit tricky understanding why the problem is arising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens, if pg gem is installed with a dedicated PostgreSQL installation. they will update the pg gem soon to fix this and to distribute ruby-3.0 compatible binary gems, but until then there are 3 workarounds:

```
 1. install postgresql per pacman: ridk exec pacman -S
    mingw-w64-x86_64-postgresql and reinstall pg gem 
 2. Set RUBY_DLL_PATH=<your-path-to-postgresql>/bin as in our CI (https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/blob/4de2c7df34b23a23841b114ae6606161be44d269/appveyor.yml#L22) before
    running the ruby app. 
 3. Downgrade to ruby < 3.0, since that installs
    the binary windows gems instead.
```

For more info check [Github issue.](https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/issues/365#issuecomment-758717354)